# Celery versus djcelery

Tags: python, django, celery, djcelery

I am confused between the differences between these two applications while trying to setup celery on my django project.

What are the differences between the two if any? When reading tutorials online I see them both used, and i'm not sure which would be best for me. It appears that djcelery is kinda like celery but tailored for django? But celery doesn't need to be included in intalled apps while djcelery does.

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using Django, you should install `django-celery` from PyPI.  Celery will be installed as a dependency.

Djcelery hooks your django project in with Celery, which is a more general tool used with a variety of application stacks.

[Here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#configuring-your-django-project-to-use-celery) is Celery's getting started with Django guide, which describes installing django-celery and setting up your first tasks.

Comment: Previous versions of Celery required a separate library to work with Django, but since 3.1 this is no longer the case. >> As you can see if you follow the link provided

Answer (score 31):

Django-celery was a project that provided Celery integration for django, but it is no longer required.

You don't have to install django-celery anymore. Since version 3.1 django is supported out of the box.

So to install celery you can use pip:

```
pip install -U Celery
```

This is a note from [Celery First Steps with Django Tutorial](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#using-celery-with-django)

> Note:
>
> Previous versions of Celery required a separate library to work with
>   Django, but since 3.1 this is no longer the case. Django is supported
>   out of the box now so this document only contains a basic way to
>   integrate Celery and Django. You will use the same API as non-Django
>   users so it’s recommended that you read the First Steps with Celery
>   tutorial first and come back to this tutorial. When you have a working
>   example you can continue to the Next Steps guide.

Answer (score 0):

Previous versions of Celery required a separate library to work with Django, but since 3.1 this is no longer the case. Django is supported out of the box now so this document only contains a basic way to integrate Celery and Django. You’ll use the same API as non-Django users: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#configuring-your-django-project-to-use-celery